# Incompatible Tensorlayer, Tensorflow and numpy version

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorlayer

I am struggling to install `tensorflow 2.0.0` and `tensorlayer 2.0.0`.

`ERROR: tensorflow 2.0.0 has requirement numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0, but you'll have numpy 1.14.0 which is incompatible.`

`ERROR: tensorlayer 2.0.0 has requirement numpy<1.16,>=1.14, but you'll have numpy 1.18.0 which is incompatible.`

It shows the conflict in the requirement of numpy version. I tried downgrading tensorflow but it doesn't support tensorlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorlayer website recommends the following procedure:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1 # specific version  (YOU SHOULD INSTALL THIS ONE NOW)
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu # GPU version
pip3 install tensorflow # CPU version
pip3 install tensorlayer
```